# how do you programatically add markers to the polymer google map element

Tags: google-maps, polymer

Trying out polymer and wanted to know how to add a marker element to the polymer element.  I know how to add the marker to a standard google map.  Should I just insert a marker object into the google-map elements marker array?  If so whats the signature and is there an example?  Do I need to call some sort of map init or refresh after I do so, or does it update automatically?

```
   (function() {
      Polymer({
        is: 'users-map',

        created: function(){
          this.loadMap(this.data[0]);
        },

        loadMap: function(row) {
          var map = document.querySelector('#users-location-map');
          row.users.forEach(function (user) {
            var location = user.location;
            var markerOptions = {
              position: {lat: location[1], lng: location[0]},
              //map: map //can't set this otherwise it throws an error on finding the google library
            };
            if (!user.online) {
              markerOptions.icon = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|666666';
            }

            map.markers.push(something); //how should I instanstiate this something
//            new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions); //normally I would just do this 
          });
        },
```

The answer below works if I comment out the map assingment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if you are using the [google-map](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map) and [google-map-marker](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/blob/master/google-map-marker.html) or the google map API directly.

If you use the `google-map` and `google-map-marker` elements this approach should work:

```
marker = document.createElement('google-map-marker');
marker.longitude = location[0];
marker.latitude = location[1];
marker.icon = 'ICON_UR'
Polymer.dom(this.$.map).appendChild(marker);
```

If you use the google map API directly your normal appraoch with `new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);` should work fine.

Comment: I also noticed that my map variable is showing up as null, in my template I use  <google-map id="users-location-map" > ... am I selecting it correctly with my query selector?

Comment: If I select it outside of the polymer constructor or ready function, as script in the template file itself, it finds the reference.

Comment: ok, so fixed the dom reference by changing it to the ready event.  However I still get an issue where it cannot get reference to google maps in the google-map-marker element.  Do I have to hard code a reference to the google maps api script even though it's in the web component?

Comment: there are a couple of issues. You shouldn't use `document.querySelector` to access any elements inside your local DOM (template). You should rather use `Polymer.dom(this).querySelector` or better Polymer's node finding (ie. `this.$.usersLoationMap`). Also you have to wait for the `google-map-ready` event to access the `map` reference. See the [component page](http://googlewebcomponents.github.io/google-map/components/google-map/) for more infos.

Comment: You can also try to use `dom-repeat` together with `google-map-marker` to add markers decleratively to your map.

Comment: so I cleared the google reference error - if I set marker.map = map it causes that error.  Not sure why but when I commented it out it works.

Comment: yeah you actually don't need to set `marker.map = this.map` because the `google-map-marker` element will do it for you and at a time when you create the marker the map reference is not initialized yet (that's the reason why you get the error). I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had same task early and have solution by this question. I hope my example will have in future for solution.

For example we have google-map polymer in our html:

```
<google-map map="{{map}}" latitude="40.730610" longitude="-73.935242" zoom="5" click-events="true" mouse-events="true" api-key="{{you_api_key}}" disable-default-ui>
</google-map>
```

And for dynamically create marker on google-map by click and add EventListener for drag event I write script like this:

```
<script> var map = document.querySelector('google-map');
        map.addEventListener('google-map-click', function (e) {
            let marker = document.createElement('google-map-marker');
            let latLng = e.detail.latLng;
            marker.setAttribute('latitude', latLng.lat());
            marker.setAttribute('longitude', latLng.lng());
            marker.setAttribute('title', "Marker name");
            marker.setAttribute('draggable', true);
            marker.setAttribute('click-events', true);
            marker.setAttribute('mouse-events', true);
            marker.addEventListener('google-map-marker-dragend', function (e) {
                let latLng = e.detail.latLng;
                marker.setAttribute('latitude', latLng.lat());
                marker.setAttribute('longitude', latLng.lng());
            });
            Polymer.dom(map).appendChild(marker);
        });
        </script>
```

Hope it help in future. Thanks.